# Phonegap plugin : Uncaught TypeError

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have created Phonegap CallLog plugin (similar to the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408313/phonegap-calllog-plugin) and made it compatible to 2.7.0) and integrated that with my code. But its giving error on

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.plugins.CallLog.list('all', onSuccess, onError);
}
```

saying

```
E/Web Console(869): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CallLog' of undefined  at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:15
```

Strangely the error is on tag **Web Console** and I am getting **sucess** callback on the plugin. And even able to see the call history in the log file.

So should I ignore this error or will this haunt me later if I do so.